# How to get category of sub items defined as a separate row in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table in SQL Server 2017 like below:

```
Type Description
H    General Income
H    Property Income
R    Rent
R    Parking
R    Storage
H    Cash Flow 
H    Other Income
R    Specials
```

Here, H refers to `Header` and R refers to `Role`. The roles belong to the header defined above them. For example, `General Income` has no role defined yet but `Property Income` has three roles under it - `rent`, `parking` and `storage`.

My expected output is:

```
Header             RoleDescription
General Income    
Property Income    Rent
Property Income    Parking
Property Income    Storage
Cash Flow
Other Income       Specials
```

How can I get this, I couldn't find it. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I have an ID column, yes, I believe I can use it for ordering.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* (multi)sets.  Without a column specifying the ordering, your question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your table has an ordering column, you can approach this by using a cumulative conditional sum to define the groups.

Then there is a trick.  Use conditional aggregation for the role and conditional aggregation with a window function for the header:

```
select max(max(case when type = 'H' then description end)) over (partition by grp) as header,
       max(case when type = 'R' then description end) as role
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by type, grp order by <ordering col) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   sum(case when type = 'H' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by <ordering col>) as grp
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by seqnum
order by grp, seqnum;
```